# Automatic Key-Value Observing in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

As I learn more about KVO and KVC, I have become curious -

How does NSObject provide automatic KVO when accessing setter methods?

If I create a new object with an accessor named setName,

how does an observer get notified when someon calls

[obj setName:@"Mystery"];

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I always explain to people that "nothing is magic in Cocoa; it's just code." But KVO borders on magic. It's called isa-swizzling. Your class is transformed at runtime (the first time anyone observes you) into a dynamically generated sub-class that overloads all getters and setters. Calls to `-class` are wired to lie to you and return the old class, so you won't see the magic subclasses except in the debugger if you look directly at the `isa` pointer.

Noticing that KVO must be bizarre is a major step in Cocoa enlightenment. Congratulations.

[Key-Value Observing Implementation Details](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/KVOImplementation.html)